# how to delete a textfields value textfield.setText(" "); does not work

Tags: java, button, textfield

how to delete a textfields value when a button clicked in java because textfield.setText(" "); does not work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
    if(arg0.getSource()==ok){ 
        String temp=textField.getText(); 
        textField.setText("hello "+ temp); 
    } 
    if(arg0.getSource()==cancel)
    { 
        textField.setText(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: more code would be highly recommanded..

Comment: Please edit your original post and put your code in there. EDT: Btw, you're setting text to `null`, not `""`. Also, does your if-statement block exexute? the `if(arg0.getSource() == cancel)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talking about Class `JTextField` you need exactly method `setText("")` to delete text from textfield.

Maybe your problem in action listener which you linked with button, try this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Clear TextField");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        textfield.setText("");
        //textfield.setText(null); // or try this
    }
});
```